# EF How can I update my Database with Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-database-first

So, i started with this command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "ConnectionString" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Context MyContext -DataAnnotations -Force
```

*I think ConnectionString is self-explanatory.

After that, i see in my project the represented classes from the database.

**Now My Question:**
How can i update the database correctly?

I started with adding an migration.

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

Now I try to use this migration on my database with the following command.

```
dotnet ef database update
```

**Finally i get an Error:**

Error Number:2714,State:6,Class:16
There is already an object named '...' in the database.

When i try to add an new migration, I use the migration command and the name of the migration. But the InitialCreate migration start first.

Can anyone help me with my problem?
Or what is my mistake. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57358438/5045688

Comment: Thank you, but in this case it is not a good choice to change this in the migration file. Migrations are something like a historical log for changes to your database. @AlexanderPetrov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start from code-first. Then `add-migration` and `update-database`. Check the Database, you will find one more table named `dbo._EFMigrationHistory`.

[image]

This table has the record of "migration file name" and "efcore version"

[image]
[image]
[image]

So you could create this table on your own. and fill any "migration file name" and "efcore version". It will skip listed files and use the files which not in this table yet. After update, it will record  the used migration file.
(You could copy the "dbo._EFMigrationHistory" from another code-first project)